# Product List - Sometimes show duplicate products

Tags: product-list

I have a problem and can't find any solution since hours.

When I'm viewing a Category and click through the pages sometimes a product is showing multiple times e.g. on Page 1 and Page 2 - exactly the same article (sku).

So far I could discover this behavior with sort order: by name.
I think the problem is that every execution of "ORDER BY name" returns a different subset of products because of many articles names a pretty much identical.

But I'm not sure if this is really the problem.

I deactivated all extension in community and local and reactivate the default Template ... the problem still exist (all indexes are refreshed).

Hope someone can help.

Many thanks

*** Update 18.06.2013 ***

Following the SQL-Query from Page 1 and Page 2

**# Page 1**

```
SELECT `e`.*, `cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position`, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price`, IF(at_name.value_id > 0, at_name.value, at_name_default.value) AS `name` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id=1 AND cat_index.visibility IN(2, 4) AND cat_index.category_id='130' INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `at_name_default` ON (`at_name_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_name_default`.`attribute_id` = '65') AND `at_name_default`.`store_id` = 0 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `at_name` ON (`at_name`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_name`.`attribute_id` = '65') AND (`at_name`.`store_id` = 1) ORDER BY `name` asc LIMIT 5
```

Returning the following entity_id's

44419

36243

36235

29435

36386 [In Frontend 36330]

The Article with entity_id 36386 is "Bugatti Herren eleganter Schnürschuh" with SKU: 650243 which is also in the Category.
There are 9 configurable products with this exact same name. (sku: 640735, 650243, 650244, 650245, 650246, 650248,  650249, 650250, 650251)

No idea why. The products are imported via 3rd-Party Interface. But can this be a problem for Magento/Pagination having multiple articles with the same name?

**# Page 2**

```
SELECT `e`.*, `cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position`, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price`, IF(at_name.value_id > 0, at_name.value, at_name_default.value) AS `name` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id=1 AND cat_index.visibility IN(2, 4) AND cat_index.category_id='130' INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `at_name_default` ON (`at_name_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_name_default`.`attribute_id` = '65') AND `at_name_default`.`store_id` = 0 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `at_name` ON (`at_name`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_name`.`attribute_id` = '65') AND (`at_name`.`store_id` = 1) ORDER BY `name` asc LIMIT 5 OFFSET 5
```

Returning the following entity_id's

36330

36584

36354

28324

29175 [In Frontend 29183]

The Last Product in Query isn't the same as in the frontend.

*** Update2 18.06.2013 ***

Ok I executed the Page 1 SQL-Statement a few times now and the result differs:

Many-Times I get this:
44419
36243
36235
29435
36386

But Sometimes that:
44419
36235
36243
29435
36354

If I carry on I think more combinations would be possible.
The ID's changed in that list are products with exacly the same name.

Could it be the problem that "ORDER BY name" couldn't get a unique order because name's are repeated so the order is a bit change? But if this is the problem two things are curious.

1) All articles with the same name (and in this category etc.) must listet together and not this OR that article.

2) This would be a known problem.

I hope someone can clear up this strange behaviour.

Comment: `ORDER BY name` should return the same result every time. It is the same result if the names are equal. If there is no difference, the order is (I think) the insert order if not reordered. But the ordering is robust.

Comment: Along with disabling extensions you might consider switching to default theme.

Comment: @Fabian Blechschmidt: Do you have an idea what else could be the problem?

Comment: @Tim: I already switch to default theme.

Comment: Do you have some kind of Full page cache system?

Comment: No only the standard Magento-Caching but in the Test-System I'm currently working with this is deactivated too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the product names aren't the same, and you only are sorting by name, the order of the products with the same name is undefined.

A simple solution might be to enable the flat product catalog of Magento under

```
System > Config > Catalog > Frontend
```

After reindexing, Magento will use the flat table for the store view on product listing pages on the frontend.
It might be that solves the issue already for you.

If it doesn't solve your problem, try adding another sorting criteria, for example the `entity_id`.

You can do that using an event observer for the `catalog_product_collection_load_before` event. (`$observer->getCollection()->setOrder('entity_id', 'ASC');`).

After that, the order will be defined, even if the product names are the same.

Comment: Hey Vinai, thanks for your solution as far as I can see the problem is solved. I used the Observer-Method because to add a additional criteria was also my thought but I can't belive that this is necessary. Isn't it a Magento-Bug as long as the product-name is no unique attribute? Anyway Thanks a lot!

Comment: Multiple (visible) products with the same name are a quite rare scenario - at least I haven't encountered that in any project so far.

Comment: The same problem exists when sorting by Price, and products with the same price exists

Answer (score 2):

Actually the SKU is not 100% guarantee of product uniqueness. Merging DBs or some import methods may still leave you with duplicate SKUs.

To find out if your products are duppies or not refer to products ID. You can either output ID in `catalog/product/list.phtml` template or just check ID in product's URL.

Comment: Even the produt-ids are the same. I make a screenshot showing Page 1, Page 2 and Page 3. On Page 1 and Page 2 you see the same product. http://i1363.photobucket.com/albums/r716/_manuel89/ps_pagination_zpsc130fd00.jpg

Comment: I just love that you used the word duppies.

Answer (score 1):

I have also same issue with repeated product in different pages in advance catalog search result and also category view page.

I have enabled Catalog Flat Product from **System > Config > Catalog > Frontend** and it resolved issue.

Thanks for the post, it is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Check the SQL-Query go into the `list.phtml` and `<?php echo $productCollection->getSelect(); ?>`.

In a collection can't one object be twice and the id is checked. The question is: why are products selected twice for different pages. And the answer can only give the sql-query.

Comment: I add the statements from page 1 and page 2 in the starting post. When i execute the Query without Limit and add WHERE e.entity_id = 36330 it only returns 1.

Answer (score 0):

Found the Solution after analyzing the basic magento2. I feel this is a M2 bug. This issue also exists if you have default sorting of price or name.

I used Magento2 Plugin Method to modify the listing collection.

$collection->setOrder('entity_id', 'DESC');

[Use this module](https://github.com/NikhilCPatil/magento2-modules) - Git Hub Link